# how to translate a URLError output that isn't stringed

Tags: python-2.7

So in my code i use urllib2 to "capture" URLErrors and HTTPErrors to use them in my code

```
show_error():
try:
    urllib2.urlopen(base_url)
except urllib2.HTTPError as err:
    if err.code == 404:
        return err.code
    else: return err.code

except urllib2.URLError as err:
    if err == "<urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>":
        return err
    else: return err 
print show_error()
```

The problem is that when i call 'err' in URLError, it gives me an output

> urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused

that is between <>, which i can't manipulate like a string, which is what i want so i can make an if statement like the one from HTTPError, like this:

```
except urllib2.URLError as err:
    if err[21:-21] == 111:
        return err
    else: return err
```

So basically i want to turn the quote above into a string, but don't know how.

Comment: `err` is an instance of [`urllib2.URLError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.URLError). Why do you expect to be able to manipulate it as a string without prior conversion?

Comment: wouldn't i be able to convert it after it has been instanced?

Comment: Obviously (`__str__()` always exists), but Python doesn't do the conversion automatically for you.

Comment: Yes, i used __str__ and solved my problem, thanks for the help!